# How to select a specific row based on two values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, sqldatatypes

I have a really strange problem.
I know that the first row of my table has two columns with the following values:
lat = 35.6635
lng = 139.395

The datatype is REAL (I have checked it).

I am trying to select these values with the following query:

```
select lat, lng from mytable where lat = 35.6635 and lng = 139.395
```

The output is nothing, i.e. I cannot find the values in my table.

Any idea what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REAL` type in Postgres is inexact, meaning that the exact values you used in your query may not actually be stored as is.  You should use `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` if you require exact storage.  See the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-numeric.html) for more information about exact and inexact numeric types.

As a workaround to find your record, you may try:

```
select lat, lng
from mytable
where round(lat, 1) = 35.7 and round(lng, 1) = 139.4;
```

Should the above query return more than one record, hopefully it would be clear to you which is the record you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
select lat, lng from mytable where lat > 35.6634 and lng > 139.394 and lat < 35.6636 and lng < 139.396
```

In computer world you should never compare for equivalent floating point numbers